# Pandas: Missing value imputation based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

I have a pandas data-frame which is as follows:

```
df_first = pd.DataFrame({"id": [102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103], "val1": [np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan], "val2": [5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5], "rand": [np.nan, 3, 7, 8, np.nan, 4], "val3": [5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan], "unique_date": [pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 3), pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 5), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 5), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 9), pd.Timestamp(2003, 8, 7), pd.Timestamp(2003, 9, 7)], "end_date": [pd.Timestamp(2005, 3, 3), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 7), np.nan, np.nan, pd.Timestamp(2003, 10, 7), np.nan]})
df_first

    id  val1  val2  rand  val3 unique_date   end_date
0  102   NaN   5.0   NaN   5.0  2002-03-03 2005-03-03
1  102   4.0   NaN   3.0   NaN  2002-03-05 2003-04-07
2  102   NaN   NaN   7.0   NaN  2003-04-05        NaT
3  102   NaN   NaN   8.0   NaN  2003-04-09        NaT
4  103   1.0   NaN   NaN   3.0  2003-08-07 2003-10-07
5  103   NaN   5.0   4.0   NaN  2003-09-07        NaT
```

The missing value imputation should be done in a way that there is forward fill of the values that appear in each row from the data-frame that has an `end_date` value.

The forward fill performs for as long as the `unique_date` is before the `end_date` for the same `id`.

Based on what is said in the last paragraph above, the forward fill should be done per `id`.

Lastly, the missing value imputation should take place only for certain columns that have a name that has `val` in it. An important note is that no other columns have that pattern in their name. In case I haven't made myself clear enough, the solution for the above posted data-frames is posted bellow:

```
    id  val1  val2  rand  val3 unique_date
0  102   NaN   5.0   NaN   5.0  2002-03-03
1  102   4.0   5.0   3.0   5.0  2002-03-05
2  102   4.0   5.0   7.0   5.0  2003-04-05
3  102   NaN   5.0   8.0   5.0  2003-04-09
4  103   1.0   NaN   NaN   3.0  2003-08-07
5  103   1.0   5.0   4.0   3.0  2003-08-07
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification since the whole thing seems rather complicated at first sight.

Looking forward to you answers!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Can you step me through how "val3" is forward filled for this sample data?

Comment: @coldspeed Same as the other "val" columns. Look at it this way, the person "id" started taking some medications "val" on "unique_date" and was taking them until "end_date". The "unique_date" is also associated with other events for that person "id". The other events are other columns in this case "rand". That is why there are several rows with the same "id" and different "unique_date" (Other events associated with that person happened other dates).

Comment: @sundance I know how to do this if I extract a numpy matrix from the data as well as the indexes of the columns that I want to edit. Then, make the forward imputation and convert the data back into a data-frame.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusing question as well as explanation. At the end I was able to achieve what I wanted in the following way.

```
df_first = pd.DataFrame({"id": [102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103],
                         "val1": [np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
                         "val2": [5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                         "val3": [np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4],
                         "val4": [5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan],
                         "rand": [3, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 5, 6],
                         "unique_date": [pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 3),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 5),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 5),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 9),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2003, 8, 7),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2003, 9, 7)],
                        "end_date": [pd.Timestamp(2005, 3, 3),
                                     pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 7),
                                     np.nan,
                                     np.nan,
                                     pd.Timestamp(2003, 10, 7),
                                     np.nan]})
display(df_first)

indexes = []
columns = df_first.filter(like="val").columns
for column in columns:
    indexes.append(df_first.columns.get_loc(column))

elements = df_first.values[:,indexes]
ids = df_first.values[:,df_first.columns.get_loc("id")]
start_dates = df_first.values[:,df_first.columns.get_loc("unique_date")]
end_dates = df_first.values[:,df_first.columns.get_loc("end_date")]

for i in range(len(elements)):
    if pd.notnull(end_dates[i]):
        not_nan_indexes = np.argwhere(~pd.isnull(elements[i])).ravel()
        elements_prop = elements[i,not_nan_indexes]
        j = i
        while (j < len(elements) and start_dates[j] < end_dates[i] and ids[i] == ids[j]):
            elements[j, not_nan_indexes] =  elements_prop
            j+=1

df_first[columns] = elements
df_first = df_first.drop(columns="end_date")
display(df_first)
```

Probably the solution is an overkill, but I was not able to find anything pandas specific to achieve what I wanted to.